# ¿Cómo guardar los datos de una persona en un fichero?

Tags: c++

Lo que está como comentario en el código es lo que hice:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <conio.h>
#define max 100

using namespace std;

struct fecha{
    int dia;
    int mes;
    int anyo;
};

struct persona{
    char nombre[20];
    char genero;
    int edad;
    fecha fecha_nacimiento;
};

void almacenar();
void  Rellenar_Datos(persona[],int);
persona leer_Persona();
fecha leer_Fecha();

    int n;
    persona personas[max];
int main(){

    cout<<"Numero de personas: ";
    cin>>n;

    Rellenar_Datos(personas,n);
    almacenar();
    getch();
    return 0;
}
/*
void almacenar(){
    ofstream salida;
    salida.open("strut.txt",ios::out);
    if(salida.fail()){
        cout<<"Error..";
    }else {

        salida<<Rellenar_Datos(personas,n);
    }
}
*/

void  Rellenar_Datos(persona A[],int n){

    for(int i=0;i<n;i++){
        cout<<"Personaje "<<i+1<<" "<<endl;
        A[i]=leer_Persona();
    }

}

persona leer_Persona(){
    persona p;

    cout<<"Nombre: ";
    fflush(stdin);
    cin.getline(p.nombre,20);
    cout<<"Genero: ";
    fflush(stdin);
    cin>>p.genero;
    cout<<"Edad: ";
    fflush(stdin);
    cin>>p.edad;
    cout<<"Fecha de nacimiento "<<endl;
    fflush(stdin);
    p.fecha_nacimiento = leer_Fecha(); 

    return p;
}

fecha leer_Fecha(){
    fecha f;

    cout<<"Dia: ";
    cin>>f.dia;
    cout<<"Mes: ";
    cin>>f.mes;
    cout<<"Anio: ";
    cin>>f.anyo;

    return f;
}
```

Comment: Disculpa, que es lo que es lo que est en comentario, osea funcion clases, no se, y que quieres hacer?

Comment: lo q esta como comentario es lo q intente hacer....lo que quiero hacer es que los datos q e ingresado es guardarlo en un archivo de texto

Comment: Bueno, te recomiendo corregir el titulo, por que no te ayuda en nada

Comment: C++11 no es compatible con c++98, que es más antiguo. Por supuesto las etiquetas c y dev-c++ no pintan nada en este caso. Es importante etiquetar bien las preguntas para atraer al público correcto.

Comment: pon mas detalles a tu pregunta ya que no dices con que lenguaje quieres almacenar el código. ya que puedes guardarlo con cualquier editor de texto. El titulo esta mal no hace referencia a lo que quieres.

Answer (score 3):

```
salida<<Rellenar_Datos(personas,n);
```

Como has podido comprobar, esta línea no compila de ninguna de las maneras. Tu quieres guardar los datos que ha introducido el usuario... veamos cómo se almacena dicha información:

```
void  Rellenar_Datos(persona A[],int n){
    for(int i=0;i<n;i++){
        cout<<"Personaje "<<i+1<<" "<<endl;
        A[i]=leer_Persona();
    }
}
```

Como vemos, los datos solicitados se almacenan en un arreglo de tipo `persona`. Lo que tienes que hacer entonces es *serializar* la estructura `persona`. Una posible forma de conseguir esto es sobrecargar el operador de inserción:

```
std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& out, const persona& p)
{
  out.write(p.nombre,20);
  return out << p.genero << p.edad << p.fecha_nacimiento;
  // Nota: falta la sobrecarga del operador para el tipo fecha
}

void almacenar(persona A[],int n){
  ofstream salida;
  salida.open("strut.txt",ios::out);
  if(salida.fail()){
    cout<<"Error..";
  }else {
    for(int i=0;i<n;i++)
      salida<<A[i];
  }
}

// Mejor esto
const int max = 100;
// que esto
#define max 100
// ya que los defines no tienen tipado fuerte

int main(){
  // Mejor evitar el uso de variables globales
  int n;
  persona personas[max];

  cout<<"Numero de personas: ";
  cin>>n;

  Rellenar_Datos(personas,n);
  almacenar(personas,n);
  getch();
  return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

C++ ofrece dos estilos de escritura en flujos de datos:

- **Escritura con formato** ([`operator <<`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_ostream/operator_ltlt)): Escribe un dato arbitrario en el flujo de datos como si fuese una cadena de texto.
- **Escritura binaria** ([`::write`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_ostream/write)): Escribe los datos en crudo (representación binaria) en el flujo de datos.

Escoger un estilo u otro dependerá de tus necesidades, podemos ver ambos estilos:

#### Escribir `persona` con formato.

En este caso, una solución elegante sería sobrecargar el operador `<<` para flujos de datos, tanto para el objeto `persona` como para el objeto `fecha`:

```
std::ostream &operator <<(std::ostream &o, const fecha &f) {
    return (o << f.dia << ' ' << f.mes << ' ' << f.anyo);
}

std::ostream &operator <<(std::ostream &o, const persona &p) {
    return (o << p.nombre << ' ' << p.genero << ' ' << p.edad << ' ' << p.fecha_nacimiento);
}
```

Con estos operadores tu función `almacenar` podría quedar así:

```
void almacenar(persona A[],int n) {
    if (std::ofstream salida{"strut.txt"}) {
        for (int i = 0; i < n; ++i) {
            salida << A[i] << '\n';
        }
    } else {
        std::cout<<"Error...\n";
    }
}
```

Y el archivo de datos podría tener este aspecto:

> ```
> Paula++ M 38 24 3 1980
> Ricardo Tovar H 68 31 10 1950
> Chindasvinto Leovigi H 1453 30 8 564
> ```

#### Escribir `persona` binariamente.

En el caso de escritura binaria llamarás directamente a la función `write`:

```
void almacenar(persona A[],int n) {
    if (std::ofstream salida{"strut.bin"}) {
        for (int i = 0; i < n; ++i) {
            salida.write(reinterpret_cast<const char *>(&A[i], sizeof(persona));
        }
    } else {
        std::cout<<"Error...\n";
    }
}
```

El contenido del archivo será binario y en consecuencia no legible "de manera humana".